# <style> tag issue in WP widget

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to make a simple image link with :hover inside a WordPress widget which supports HTML Source Code.

Please fin my code:

```
<style>
a.filtro{
width:100px;
background: url("http://www.tk.gvdgvd.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/tokooblog_filtro-02.png");
}

a.filtro:hover{
width:100px;
background: url('http://www.tk.gvdgvd.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/tokooblog_filtro_sel-02.png');
}
</style>

<a href="http://www.tk.gvdgvd.net/?cat=10" class="filtro"></a>
```

The link simply does not appear in the page now

I don't know what's wrong here, is it something that my widget does not support my css?
Is all the "hover" css done right? maybe it's messed up too, but i can't find whats wrong with the code either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<style>
a.filtro{
width: 196px;
height: 196px;
display: block;
background: url("http://www.tk.gvdgvd.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/tokooblog_filtro-02.png");
}

a.filtro:hover{
background: url('http://www.tk.gvdgvd.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/tokooblog_filtro_sel-02.png');
}
</style>

<a href="http://www.tk.gvdgvd.net/?cat=10" class="filtro"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the most close im getting to make it work now.... but the button is behind the logo of the page..... and it has some animation that i don't know where it came from.... this is the page: http://www.tk.gvdgvd.net/ 

Maybe you could explain me what is "block" for.
thanks!

Comment: `a.filtro:hover {
display: block;
width: 100px;
background: url("http://www.tk.gvdgvd.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/tokooblog_filtro_sel-02.png");
}`

Adjust your code above with the one I gave in my answer. Also, change this:

`.main-head .right {
line-height: 135px;
text-align: right;
float: right;
}`

you are missing a float right (in case you want it to be on the right side of the header)

Comment: thank you, where did you get this from ---> .main-head .right { line-height: 135px; text-align: right; float: right; }  It's not within the text i wrote in the widget... so where should i add the float: right; then, beacause i DO want to make it in the right side of the header.... Thanks!

Comment: I inspected your code, and it was there.. Check your style.css file `(wp-content/themes/smart-mag/style.css)`. You are missing the `float:right;`

Comment: Hmmmmm, but i defined everything else (for the button) within the widget, without getting to the global stylesheet of the site. is there a way to do so? (sorry for the bad english)

Comment: If you cannot edit your style.css or don't know how to do so, then add the following line inside the <style> of the widget you made:

`.main-head .right { float: right; }`

Comment: Thank you!, I would like to upvote your answer but i have not enough reputation. Anyway, it seem like the only problem was that i was repeating attributes in the hoover.... It works now even without making it float right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
a {display:block; width:100px;height:auto;}
```

Comment: Still not working. the link is copletly missing in the page. no image is displayed at all...
Should I put something in between the <a></a> tags?

Answer (score 0):

You should first copy the css code and paste in style.css, if it does work pasting in style.css then there must be porblem with widget area.
There are couple of plugin available you can use that too. for eg :
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/text-widget
If this is doesn't work then try this one.
Alternate way is to check if you copy the same code in other wordpress and paste in widget I guess it will work.

Comment: There is no need. Style can work even inside HTML widget

Comment: I know it does work, but you should be double check it with that some time theme has code which remove spaces and style css.

Comment: Give me the link, I just checked it does work in my wordpress widget ( http://sabir.co.in/ at the bottom of sidebar)

Comment: Some times. First we go with a common solution, and if it doesn't work, we proceed with alternatives..

Comment: your code work fine in my widget please remove the negative vote on my answer

Comment: I didn't vote your answer, but the css is working for me too, i found out. here's the link: http://www.tk.gvdgvd.net/  it seems like the button is hiding behind the logo for some reason....